# Rails 3.1 mass assignment hierarchy structure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, mass-assignment

I am trying to set different access control levels (3 levels in my app) for CRUD certain model. There is no User model in the app, because I use RPAM for authentication and session for keeping track of the user. In order to set authorization levels, I created a model named user_role, to assign a role to a username. In DB, it looks like this:

```
 id | username |  role   
----+----------+---------
  1 | user1    | limited
  2 | admin    | admin
  3 | user2    | normal
```

I have a model defined like this:

```
class Treatment < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :user_roles
    attr_accessible :cust_id, :admission_time, :as=>:admin
    attr_accessible :customer_type, :as=>:limited
end
```

How could I build a hierarchical structure of role: for all the stuff that limited could do, admin can do also, but not the other way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do

```
attr_accessible :customer_type, :as=>[:admin, :limited]
```

and it'll cover for both roles.